# Populate a calculators display with the inner HTML of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use JavaScript to update a calculators display (.display) to represent whatever numbered button is clicked.

I'm attempting to use forEach to fire a click event listener on each button to fire a  updateDisplay function that updates the variable displayValue with the number inside the div.

However it's not working and I'm not getting any console errors. Can anyone help?

Abbreviated HTML looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="display">
            <p id="result-display">
            </p>
        </div>
    <div class="button-grid">
        <div class="item" id="7">
            <p>
            7
            </p>
        </div>
```

My JS is:

```
//Create variable to hold display value, create variable of display area and populate.
let displayValue = 0;
let displayArea = document.getElementById('result-display');
displayArea.innerHTML += displayValue;

//Update display with button clicked
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
button.forEach(item => {
addEventListener('click', () => {
updateDisplay();
})
});

//Update displayValue variable  
let updateDisplay = () => {
displayValue = button.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is scoping. In the loop you are looping through several buttons (which you called `button` --probably best to refer to the group of buttons in the plural. You then loop through each one correctly and add the event listener to it.

I changed your code slightly to account for accessibility (you shouldn't add event listeners to `p` as screen readers will not think to check if that is clickable, but if you just change the `p` tag to a button tag it automatically fixes a whole slew of accessibility issues.

When the event runs we need a way to figure out on which element specifically did you click. Either you can add 10+ different event listener functions (so that the correct event listener with knowledge of the number contained is run) or you must have a generic event listener which figures out which button was clicked.

Next, we have to actually reset the innerHTML of the DISPLAY_AREA not the specific button (as you had in your code may have been a typo) but the button itself already has `7` written there. What we need is: to display the new value of `displayValue` in the `displayArea`. Even better would be to write a function called:

```
const rerenderCalculatorDisplay = (newValue) => {
displayArea.innerHTML = displayValue;
}
```

If you actually want to add to the previous displayValue as the `+=` suggests you may need to first read the innerHTML and then add to it (I'm assuming since it's a calculator sometimes you're adding 4 + 4 but other times you need to control for `44`.

So you may want your rerenderCalculatorDisplay to look like:

```
const rerenderCalculatorDisplay = (addToDisplay) => {
// this function checks that what is passed is an actual number
if (!isNaN(addToDisplay))
  displayArea.innerHTML = `${displayValue}${addToDisplay}`;
// if the previous displayValue was 3 and addToDisplay is: 4 => '34'
}
```

If you prefer rather than reading the `id` of the `e.target` (as I did you could also read the `e.target.innerText`...

Or like I said you can create 10+ different event listeners one for each of the different buttons that a user can press.

Instead of:

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
button.forEach(item => {
addEventListener('click', () => {
updateDisplay();
})
```

You would do:

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
button.forEach(item => {
addEventListener('click', () => {
updateDisplay(item.id); // now updateDisplay is aware of the specific button that we want to update
})

// In this case updateDisplay will have to read from the parameter
const updateDisplay = (valueClicked) => {
  displayValue += valueClicked;
  // don't forget that in order to change what is rendered to the user we have to also do:
  displayArea.innerText = displayValue;
}
```

```js
//Create variable to hold display value, create variable of display area and populate.
let displayValue = 0;
let displayArea = document.getElementById('result-display');
displayArea.innerHTML += displayValue;

//Update display with button clicked
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
button.forEach(item => {
addEventListener('click', (e) => {
updateDisplay(e);
})
});

//Update displayValue variable  
let updateDisplay = (e) => {
displayValue = e.target.id;
displayArea.innerHTML = displayValue
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="display">
      <p id="result-display">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-grid">
    <div class="item">
      <button id="7">
      7
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this help you?